# Migrate Win10 to a different drive

Tags: windows, windows-10

I need to send my SSD where OS (Win10) is installed for RMA. Therefore, I have to migrate everything on the SSD to another drive. I understand many threads are discussing this, but in my case, it is slightly different.

I have two SSDs; let's call them `SSD_1` and `SSD_2`.

- `SSD_1` is the C: volume, i.e. where the actual Win10 OS is installed.
- `SSD_2` is the System Reserved Volume, i.e. where the bootable files are installed.

Therefore, trying booting my PC without `SSD_2` will end up with a message saying no operating system installed.

---

## Question:

Will Win10 load up if I do the following procedures:

1. do a copy and paste of everything on `SSD_1` to a different drive, say `SSD_3`;
2. shut down PC; remove `SSD_1`; enter PE;
3. and change the drive label for `SSD_3` to *C:*.

Comment: Just clone your drive.  There are dozens of free and paid programs that will clone your SSD

Comment: Thank you @Ramhound, but that won't allow me to use my PC during the period of RMA.

Comment: If you clone the SSD now, to another SSD, how will that now allow you to use your PC?

Comment: @Ramhound. Isn't there a need to change the drive label?

Comment: If you clone the drive, you would be doing a sector by sector copy, the drive label isn't important

Comment: @Ramhound, I understand this. What worries me is the boot files are installed on a separate drive. I wonder if the boot files would point to C:.

Comment: If you have SSD_3 it doesn't matter.  You are going to keep SSD_2 installed.  You only have to RMA SSD_1.  If you clone SSD_1 to SSD_3 it won't matter.  A copy and paste operation will result in a non-working installation of Windows

Comment: @Ramhound thank you for your help. I will try your suggestion.